# jQuery ScrollTop doesn't scroll to the correct position after other div collapse

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

So I have a team page I'm building for a website. On mobile its one column. When you tap an employee photo a hidden div expands showing this employees information(Title, quotes, ect ect) and any other expanded employee info divs are collapsed so this means only one hidden div is visible at a time.

The problem is when these divs expand and collapse they are taking up more or less height compared to the previous expanded div. With that said the jQuery scrollTop is going to the previous position of the div and not the top of its new location.

Is there something I can do to make it goto the top of the new expanded div?

This code is what I currently have and its ABOVE the jQuery used to expand and close the hidden divs.

```
jQuery('html, body').delay( 500 ).animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(eleClass2).offset().top }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may need to assign the offset to the parent node of your current target. Take it for what it's worth but I'd try something like:

```
jQuery('html, body').delay(500).animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery(eleClass2).parent().offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Comment: So I added that code and I'm getting an error in the console: jQuery(...).parentNode is not a function

Comment: Try .parent() that's the jQuery equivalent. my bad.

Comment: So the error is gone but I'm still having the same issue. It likes to scroll to the former position not the current. Sometimes it could be a few pixels but most of the time its a couple hundred.

I'm half tempted to expand all of these hidden divs on mobile/tablets.